# GA4 Realtime overview: I see visits, but not on the map

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I use GA4 with Google Tag Manager Server Side in custom server and All work fine.

In GA4, I see a number > 0 in "USERS IN LAST 30 MINUTES", but no "blue dots" on the map.

I can see the country of the last visitors in other pages of GA4 so I guess that at least the country (assuming it is correct) is registered. Why it's not displayed on the map? I used to correctly see data on the map in Universal.
I also can't see which pages the current users are visiting (in "Views by Page title and screen name" I see all the pages viewed in the last 30 minutes, not the current pages), something that I could see in Universal.

Can you help me?
Thanks!